# When transliterating English words to Korean, why does the first F become a ㅎ?

Tags: grammar, transliteration, etymology

This is one of the questions [from the definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74084#74084) and I would  like to get asked in the main site. (It has also be [asked and answered in Linguistics.se](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15054/2428))

When transliterating English words to Korean, why do some F sounds in the beginning of the word turn into a ㅎinstead of ㅂ or ㅍ? For example,

Family Mart -> 회미리 마트
Foundation -> 화운데이션

This does not happen to the F sound in the middle or end of a word
coffee -> 커피
golf -> 골프

Comment: I know it was answered elsewhere, but just looking a bit on naver, I see it is shown with both ㅎ and ㅍ, while they do have different sounds, i think its mostly based on how they entered the language
                  "리퀴드**파**운데이션(1회 출현) 리퀴드**화**운데이션메이크업(1회 출현)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using ㅍ for all /f/ sounds is the standard, and should be preferred.

Using 후/호 for /f/ sounds comes from Japanese. Japanese doesn't have /f/, rather they have /ɸ/. So they use /ɸ/ for transliterating /f/ sounds from English. Korean doesn't have /ɸ/, so we use the closest sound to tranliterate from Japanese, which is 후/호(/hw/).

So "family"(/fӕməli/) became /ɸemiri/ in Japanese, then borrowed into 훼미리/hwemiri/ to Korean. The correct transliteration is 패밀리.

Comment: Note that `ㅍ` in `패밀리` sounds as /p/.

Answer (score 8):

Family Mart is a Japanese company whose name is ファミリーマート (훼미리- 마-또) and 훼미리 is a transliteration of Japanese, not English.

화운데이션 also comes from Japanese ファ(ウ)ンデーション (화운데-숀).

Japan ruled Korea from 1910 to 1945 and many Korean words were influenced by Japanese or borrowed from it. The F sound is one of them.

Nowadays, f sound is always transliterated to ㅍ as in

> 'Fighting (Way to go, Keep it up, Go go) is transliterated to 파이팅 even
>   though it is pronounced '화이팅' by most Korean people.